# How to give a different comparator to different instances of the same heap java?

Tags: java

I have to write a generic heap priority queue, and three separate comparator classes that compare different things. How do I assign the different comparators to each instance of the heap. So in my main I'll have something like

```
GenericHeap D= new GenericHeap <String> ();

GenericHeap S= new GenericHeap <Integer> ();
```

and then the methods of D, such as add, and remove would have to use of the comparators I've made, and S would have to use a different one. How do I assign a comparator to each instance of the heap class. All of the heap have to be written with the same code, so I don't understand how this works?

Comment: just pass comparator object it in the constructor, and use it in your heap Implementation to compare objects. That is how it is done in Java Collections framework [PriorityQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take it as a constructor parameter

```
GenericHeap D = new GenericHeap<String>(new MyStringComparator());
```

or via a mutator function

```
   D.setComparator(new MyStringComparator());
```

Either way you should make these functions take something like an IMyComparatorInterface which has a method such as Compare(T item1, T item2)

```
public class MyStringComparator implements IMyComparatorInterface
```

Comment: This isn't C#: **don't** start interface names with `I` and **do** have camelCase method names such as `compare`. Also, there is already an interface for what you are suggesting: `Comparator<T>`.

Comment: Fair point about naming conventions for the language.  As for the existing comparator, maybe :) School projects are school projects and the requirements are unknown

Comment: Ok so if I do it as a parameter how would I set this up? I tried public GenericHeap(Comparator C) {
        heap = (E[]) new Object[capacity];
        C compare=new C();                                            but it appears that this doesn't work?

Comment: I....so you seem to be missing the basics of how to instantiate and pass parameters.

You would simply have a member variable "Comparator myComparator;" that you set to "C" in the constructor (myComparator = C) (though fix your naming, it should be lower case) and you would instantiate it in the call

Comment: yes, I've never really understand passing a class as a parameter, how to pass an instance of a class, but not a class in general.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than implementing Comparator, you could create different ones for each type and call .compare on those. Replace List with GenericHeap:

```
    Comparator<List<String>> stringListComparator = new Comparator<List<String>>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(List<String> arg0, List<String> arg1) {
            // TODO Add comparison code
            return 0;
        }

    };

    Comparator<List<Integer>> integerListComparator = new Comparator<List<Integer>>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(List<Integer> arg0, List<Integer> arg1) {
            // TODO Add comparison code
            return 0;
        }

    };

    stringListComparator.compare(Collections.emptyList(), Collections.emptyList());
    integerListComparator.compare(Collections.emptyList(), Collections.emptyList());
```

Or with Java 8 lamdas:

```
    Comparator<List<String>> stringListComparator = (p1, p2) -> {
        // TODO Add comparison code
        return 0;
    };

    Comparator<List<Integer>> integerListComparator = (p1, p2) -> {
        // TODO Add comparison code
        return 0;
    };

    stringListComparator.compare(Collections.emptyList(), Collections.emptyList());
    integerListComparator.compare(Collections.emptyList(), Collections.emptyList());
```

Alternatively, implement Comparable, pass in a Comparator in the constructor and call that from .compare as follows:

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class StackOverflowExample implements Comparable<StackOverflowExample> {

    private final Comparator<StackOverflowExample> comparator;

    public StackOverflowExample(Comparator<StackOverflowExample> comparator) {
        this.comparator = comparator;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(StackOverflowExample arg0) {
        return comparator.compare(this, arg0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Comparator<StackOverflowExample> comparator = (p1, p2) -> {
            // TODO Add comparison code
        };
        StackOverflowExample stackOverflowExample = new StackOverflowExample(comparator);
    }

}
```